NBG Class Theory - Can FOL be defined in terms of "mental notions"?
I am currently exploring defining mathematical theories in terms of mental concepts rather than as being formalized in yet other mathematical theories.
In the single-sorted presentation of NBG class theory, we have a single sort (a class), and a single binary relation, 'in'.
I will think of a "sort" as a "type of thing", and a "binary relation" as a "relationship". So, a "class" will be "a group of things", and "in" will be "is inside of".
We may also need essential mental concepts for first-order logic. I will think of "equality" as being "the same thing".
The axiom of regularity says that "Nothing can be inside of itself." (As a mental notion, it sounds like this axiom could be rejected, actually.)
The axiom of extensionality says that "Even if we have two different cases of the same thing, in this theory, we are focusing on things in terms of their defining characteristics; so if we have two copies of the same collection, we do not treat them like two separate things, but instead as examples of the same collection." (Similarly, this mental notion could be easily and coherently rejected.)
The axiom of pairing says that "If you have some collections, you can make a collection of those collections." (Mentally, I think this is saying, when you have a thing, and then you have multiple things, we consider multiple things to be itself a thing. I think this is one of the deepest and most interesting axioms, as a mental notion, and would be interested in analyzing it further.)
The axiom of union says "If you have some collections, you can put all the things inside them together into one collection."
The axiom of power says that "If you have a collection, you can go inside and take out anything inside that. That also is a collection."
(I wonder if both of the above two can be simplified. They seem mainly to be based on the axiom of pairing, which is simply that we consider a multiplicity of things to be itself a thing... we could instead call it the axiom of Reification. Then union and power do not add reification, but only certain "mental operations" on collections (which it is already understood get reified). Power adds a special way to identify new things from what you already have, and Union adds a special way to put things together that I feel like is already quite implicit in the axioms from before...)
I'm realizing that I don't actually understand the axiom of infinity that well from this perspective:

I think it could be saying, "Imagine a collection of collections. Take any of those collections and put them together. Imagine if you could keep putting any of those collections together. Could all of those collections still be collected in a very large collection? Yes."
or
"Imagine a collection of collections. Take any of those collections inside and pull them out. You can make a new collection of them. No matter how many times you do this, it will still count as a collection."
Which makes it seem like the most interesting and controversial axiom of them all, so far.
From this perspective, how might we define first-order logic, as a formal system, within these mental notions?
For example:
Since we do not have urelements, which already seems like a mistake, we have to claim certain collections are or stand for other things we want them to represent, like "symbols". So we say:
Imagine you have any collection whatsoever. Let's keep track of the things inside, since we will be using them in a certain way. Let's call them our 'symbols', since they will be used to "stand" for something.
The theory can be developed from here...

@JuliusHamilton Sorry, but I do not feel able to follow posts like the present one. I need an introduction in simple words what the philosophical or academic problem is and why it is important. Similarly to the good custom to start an academic talk with picking up the audience before addressing the experts with my own solution.

@JuliusHamilton This sure sounds a lot like Frege's logic of concepts. You have to weaken extensionality for the logic of concepts, since distinct concepts can have the same extension (e.g. Santa Claus and unicorns), and weakening extensionality lets you have ur-elements too, if you do it right. Your question itself doesn't make sense to me, though. Why would you want to define FOL within this system? I would expect you to define this system in terms of FOL. Don't you want to use FOL along with one extra relation ("in") added to the alphabet, i.e., the language of first-order set theory?

The notion of conceptual metaphor might aid you. I would start with Where Mathematics Comes From if you're interested in an approach to a psychological foundation to mathematics rather than a formal logical one. Also review Intuitionism in Philosophy of Mathematics (SEP)
You say:

I am currently exploring defining mathematical theories in terms of mental concepts rather than as being formalized in yet other mathematical theories.

The definition of a concept (SEP) is a bit contentious, but if you are holding them in distinction to formal theories, then perhaps you mean our intuitive faculties. Intuitionistic type theory (SEP) for instance, has two notions of a containment, one intuitionistic and the other formalized. Certainly, instead of logic, math can be seen in terms of being grounded in psychological processes. The study with that disposition is called numerical cognition and relies on modern brain-imaging methods among others.
You ask:

From this perspective, how might we define first-order logic, as a formal system, within these mental notions?

Absolutely, but first you must realize that much mathematics is built on linguistic constructions, and therefore, some portion of studying numerical cognition is modeling the formal semantics of the natural language grammar. For instance, there is a distinction between philosophical predication and grammatical predication. As Wittgenstein noted, confusing problems of language with problems of logic is a major problem, and late LW's view was that problems of philosophy are essentially reducible to problems of language. From the WP article Therapeutic Approach:

he therapeutic approach to philosophy sees philosophical problems as misconceptions that are to be therapeutically dissolved. The approach stems from Ludwig Wittgenstein... "There is not a single philosophical method, though there are indeed methods, different therapies, as it were." — Ludwig Wittgenstein, Philosophical Investigations, §133d

So, the same might be said of understanding the foundations of mathematics, which of course, is a heavily philosophical endeavor since it might be seen as an exercise in metaphysical grounding (SEP).
But setting aside the linguistic analysis inherent in the foundations of mathematics, there has been some speculation on the conceptual basis of mathematics which is championed by philosophers of language coming from a particular linguistics community: the cognitive semanticists. There, your "intuitive" notion of classes already has a name: the Metaphor of Containment. In fact, Lakoff and Núñez have a book that lists four basic conceptual metaphors that support all of mathematics.
Thus, according to that work, it would seem to be possible (and I'm not sure if anyone has made the effort already) to ground FOL in conceptual explanation (particularly in formalizations of concepts) rather than other formal systems. The ontological primitives such as the entities and operations in FOL must in someway reduce to natural language constructions and conceptual metaphors, both of which there is existent academic literature (GB). Whether that has been done or not would require some research in the literature of conceptual metaphors and mathematics (PhilPapers.org).
